# How to center align a button in mat-grid-tile-footer

Tags: angular-material, angular-flex-layout, angular-material-6, angular-material-5, angular-material-7

I have  `mat-grid-list` where I am listing items in the view.

**issue 1:**
Each item has a `mat-grid-tile-footer` section where I display a angular material button. The button is currently aligned left side in the footer section and I want to align the button in the centre of `mat-grid-tile-footer` using below code ( flex row centre is also not working inside footer) but it's not working. Any ideas ?

**issue 2:**
On applying `[style.background]="'white'"` to the footer the `mat-raised-button` text also gets invisible. Seems like it is overriding the button behaviour too. Any ideas ?

```
<mat-grid-tile-footer [style.background]="'white'">
   <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <button mat-raised-button>Try me</button>
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile-footer>
```

**TRY 1**
On using `margin: auto` I see the changed styles is not picked up and below is the used styles

```
.mat-grid-tile .mat-grid-tile-header>*, .mat-grid-tile .mat-grid-tile-footer>* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: inherit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**: adding CSS `.mat-grid-tile-footer div{ margin: auto; }` resolves it

**Issue 2**: unable to observe the behavior of the text getting invisible

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpp3vz)

**update**: in light of comment below...
remove `margin: 0` from the class in your question... so that the CSS is only:

```
.mat-grid-tile-footer div{ margin: auto; }
.mat-grid-tile .mat-grid-tile-header>*, .mat-grid-tile .mat-grid-tile-footer>* {
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: inherit;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not working. I updated in my question.